# create a friendly url using the rewrite mod

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

im trying to create a friendly url using the rewrite mod in php with no sucess!

without the friendly url

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/lyrics/index.php?letter=a
```

with the friendly url

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/lyrics/a/
```

my attempt with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^lyrics/([A-Z])/?$ /index.php?letter=$1 [L]
```

help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ReWrite Trailing Slash problem](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you always expecting an uppercase letter? If not, I would add the case-insensitive flag `NC` as below:

```
RewriteRule ^lyrics/([A-Z])/?$ /index.php?letter=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it... i was missing something(the one thing showing in bold below) + added rexmac tip...

RewriteRule ^lyrics/([a-z])/?$ /**lyrics**/index.php?letter=$1 [NC,L]